# PHP SQL UPDATE using variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I currently have a script to upload photos, at the moment it uploads multiple images adding a new row to the mySQL database each time a new one is created. However I want the user to only be able to upload 1 image maximum.

I have therefore changed the register script to insert a row straight in to the database with a default image for each new user that registers.

The image upload script once logged in currently uses the below line to put the data in to the database

```
$sql2= "INSERT INTO `profile_photo` (`profile_id`,`title`,`size`,`type`,`reference`)
            VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','$title','$size','$type','$pic'); ";
```

However this is not how I want this to work; I believe the resolve would be to change this to an UPDATE row.

This is causing an issue when I change the line, I believe I have not quite grasped the concept of updating rows in mySQL.

Please can you advise?

Comment: Are you looking for UPDATE query ? against that insert query ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql2= 
"INSERT INTO `profile_photo` (`profile_id`,`title`,`size`,`type`,`reference`)
VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','$title','$size','$type','$pic')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = VALUES(title), size = VALUES(size), type = VALUES(type), reference = VALUES(reference)";
```

Would solve this if the `profile_id` column got the index `unique`.

**Behavior**
This will `INSERT` all the data in a new row if the `profile_id` isn't already added. If it is, it will run an `UPDATE` instead.

However your code is pretty much begging for mysql injections. Do read up on this before it ruins your site.

[Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/), for your consideration.

Read up on [DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `profile_id` is your unique key:

```
$sql2= "
INSERT INTO 
    `profile_photo` (`profile_id`,`title`,`size`,`type`,`reference`)
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','$title','$size','$type','$pic')
    on duplicate key update set title='$title', size='$size', type='$type', reference='$reference'; ";
```

You can also use the replace into:

```
$sql2= "
Replace into 
    `profile_photo` (`profile_id`,`title`,`size`,`type`,`reference`)
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','$title','$size','$type','$pic')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question misses some information.

- You might want to look into the [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/replace.html) statement
- Or look up the [MySQL UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/update.html) reference manual page

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to execute the UPDATE sql statement:

```
$sql3= "UPDATE `profile_photo` SET `title`='" . mysql_real_escale_string($title) .
       "', `size`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($size) . 
       "', `type`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($type) .
       "', `reference`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($pic) .
       "' WHERE `profile_id`=" . $_SESSION['id'];
```

Comment: The OP said that he wanted to use one statement. The `on duplicate` answers provided will allow him/her to use a single query to either insert or update the row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)?